# How to insert rows of data in order using MERGE Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to have the inserted rows in the same order as in the
source select statement - i.e. ORDER BY TMP.DEF_DATA_SK. But they are
inserted somewhat randomly.

With Simple **Insert into Select** Statement it can be Done But i Want it to be done using **MERGE**.

SQL is as follows

```
MERGE 
INTO 
HCI_STD_STAGING.STAGE.DEF_DATA 
TRG 
USING 
     ( SELECT  TMP.DEF_DATA_SK,
              TMP.VAL, 
              TMP.CD,
              TMP.DESCR,
              TMP.DEF_TP_SK TYPE_SK ,--
              TMP.PRN_SK PARENT, --
              PRN.DEF_DATA_SK PRN_SK, PRN.VAL PRN_VAL,
              TYP.DEF_TP_SK
              ,PRN_PRN.VAL DB
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TMP.DEF_DATA_SK) AS RowNum
       FROM 
       HCI_STD_STAGING.STAGE._DEF_DATA_TMP TMP
       LEFT JOIN HCI_STD_STAGING.STAGE.DEF_TP TYP
       ON TMP.DEF_TP_SK = TYP.CD --TYPE
        LEFT JOIN HCI_STD_STAGING.STAGE.DEF_DATA PRN
         ON TMP.PRN_SK = PRN.VAL  -- SCH
          INNER JOIN HCI_STD_STAGING.STAGE.DEF_DATA PRN_PRN
           ON PRN.PRN_SK = PRN_PRN.DEF_DATA_SK AND TMP.DB = PRN_PRN.VAL --AND 
        TMP.SCH = PRN.VAL
        WHERE TMP.DEF_TP_SK = 'Table Object'

        GROUP BY 
        TMP.DEF_DATA_SK,
              TMP.VAL, 
              TMP.CD,
              TMP.DESCR,
              TMP.DEF_TP_SK  ,
              TMP.PRN_SK ,
              PRN.DEF_DATA_SK , PRN.VAL ,
              TYP.DEF_TP_SK
              ,PRN_PRN.VAL

      --order by TMP.DEF_DATA_SK

    ) SRC
     ON SRC.VAL = TRG.VAL
     AND SRC.PRN_SK = TRG.PRN_SK
     AND SRC.DEF_TP_SK = TRG.DEF_TP_SK
     WHEN NOT MATCHED
     THEN
      INSERT 
      (
      VAL,CD, DESCR, DEF_TP_SK, PRN_SK
      )
      VALUES ( SRC.VAL, SRC.CD,SRC.DESCR,SRC.DEF_TP_SK,SRC.PRN_SK  );
```

Comment: Tables do not have an order, and you can always get back rows in any order unless your queries have `ORDER BY` to retrieve them in that order. Table rows are stored on disk in a physical order, but that's an implementation detail that doesn't change the main fact that, under normal circumstances, you observe that order only by accident and not because the system guarantees it. What is the problem you're trying to solve by having an "order" to inserted rows? It *should* mean the way you're reading the rows later is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee for the order of insertion of the rows into the table.

However, if your table has primary key, the records will be ordered by the primary key because upon the creation of primary key, it will also create a clustered index on the table based on that primary key. If the primary key defined as identity, the only guarantee is that the identity values will be generated based on the ORDER BY clause.

But if you don't want to put primary key on the table, you can just create clustered index on the table based on a column. There are some other concerns about clustered index to be considered based on your needs. Please take a look at clustered index as follows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017

so you could get the rows stored as you expected.

Comment: Be careful: the rows will only be *physically ordered* by the clustered index key. That does not mean that if you do `SELECT * FROM table` without an `ORDER BY`, you will get back the rows in this order, and that's the insidious thing. If no parallelism is involved, the optimizer will pick a plan that scans the table linearly in index order, but this is not guaranteed. With more complicated queries, or if a parallel scan is involved, you can and *will* get rows back in whatever manner SQL Server deems most efficient. If you need an order, *always* specify `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Agree, yes that is another concern to apply clustered index, plenty things to be considered before using clustered index, the records will be physically ordered, and certainly doing SELECT without an ORDER BY doesn't mean it will appears in order. But what I am talking about here is that the Identity column can be created in order based on the order column. In my case and experience, as I have primary key on my table, and the primary key is the identity column as its ordered, when i select the table, it appeared in order based on the primary key column

Comment: @JeroenMostert - even without parallelism within the query, the optimizer can sometimes piggy-back on an already running table scan due to some other query and produce results out of order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: really? That is *so cool*. I've never seen it do that, but I would be thrilled if I did. :-)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx