# SQL Merge SOURCE order and OUTPUT order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

Consider an SQL MERGE statement merging 4 rows using a derived table into Target like so:

```
MERGE Target AS T USING 
(VALUES 
  (?, ?, ?), 
  (?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?),
  (?, ?, ?),
) as S(Account_ID,Device_ID,Device_Name)

ON T.Account_ID = S.Account_ID

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
  Account_ID = S.Account_ID, 
  Device_ID = S.Device_ID, 
  Device_Name = S.Device_Name

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
  (Account_ID,Device_ID,Device_Name)
  VALUES (S.Account_ID,S.Device_ID,S.Device_Name)

OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
```

Does the output (of inserted rows) respect the same order that is specified in the derived table? For example, assume rows 2 and 4 were inserted into Target. Does the output result maintain the same order like so [2,4].

For the tests that I performed, it seems to do it, but I could not find any reliable documentation around it.

If it helps Target has an auto-incrementing primary key as well.

Comment: Like always in SQL: Without an `order by` clause there is no garanteed order in your output.

Comment: @juergend thanks for the response. Is there a way to make the MERGE perform the inserts in the same order specified in the derived Source table? If that is possible, then I can rely on the auto-incrementing key to sort the OUTPUT.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149978/how-to-insert-rows-of-data-in-order-using-merge-statement) seems to suggest that with an auto-incrementing key the records would be ordered. But in my tests I just came across an instance where the SOURCE order was not respected for the inserts.

Comment: This might be worth a read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155735/is-it-safe-to-rely-on-the-order-of-an-inserts-output-clause

Comment: Aaron Bertrand  : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: For insert the docs say "INSERT queries that use SELECT with ORDER BY to populate rows guarantees how identity values are computed but not the order in which the rows are inserted." - merge doesn't comment, but one might assume it works the same.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the previous link. The suggestion to use an incremental index with the derived Source table, and then using that to sort the output result worked for my use case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many responses have pointed out, the MERGE operation does not guarantee any ordering for the upserted rows.

However, the approach outlined [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155735/is-it-safe-to-rely-on-the-order-of-an-inserts-output-clause) worked for my use case by specifying an incremental index (SourceId) for the rows and then doing some in-memory processing (in my NodeJS code) to sort the OUTPUT response by the SourceId.

```
MERGE Target AS T USING 
(VALUES 
  (1, ?, ?, ?), 
  (2, ?, ?, ?),
  (3, ?, ?, ?),
  (4, ?, ?, ?),
) as S(SourceId, Account_ID,Device_ID,Device_Name)

ON T.Account_ID = S.Account_ID

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
  Account_ID = S.Account_ID, 
  Device_ID = S.Device_ID, 
  Device_Name = S.Device_Name

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
  (Account_ID,Device_ID,Device_Name)
  VALUES (S.Account_ID,S.Device_ID,S.Device_Name)

OUTPUT $action, S.SourceId, inserted.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

[**The documentation on `OUTPUT` *explicitly* states:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> There is no guarantee that the order in which the changes are applied to the table and the order in which the rows are inserted into the output table or table variable will correspond.

Which makes perfect sense, as there is never a guarantee how any query or DML is executed. the compiler is free to reorder things or parallelize, as long as the semantics are the same.

More to the point: the `MERGE` itself is not guaranteed to insert or update in any particular order. This is irrespective of any clustered or no-clustered indexes, primary keys or `IDENTITY` columns.